# Register for an event and create an account on one page

Tags: forms, users

It's been a while since I've used Drupal and I now need to implement the following but can't seem to determine how. I have a site that's set up for event registration and need visitors to be able to sign up for an account as part of that one-page process. They'll then need to be able to edit their registration details and such but that part is in hand. What I'm not seeing is a way to combine account creation with the submission of non-profile form data all in one go.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this existing answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10616/how-to-register-and-create-a-node-in-the-same-form), I could find the [Inline Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_registration) module. It lets you register while creating a node at the same time (one form). Since this is node-specific, this may allow a "event registration" content type to be defined then assigned to the user registration form.